# mysqli fetch array return null as result

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

have no idea my result return nothing

```
    if ($stmt2->execute()) {
        $photo_items = $stmt2->get_result();

        while ($imgArray = $photo_items->fetch_array()) {
        }
            echo  $imgArray[] = $imgArray;
        }
```

and I also tried this

```
            echo  $imgArray[] = $imgArray['mycolname'];
```

Comment: @SatishSharma yes, not PDO

Comment: first check $photo_items and then print_r($imgArray); and check if it return something or not?

Comment: Try print_r($variable_with_array), you can solve you're problem with this function

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while ($img = $photo_items->fetch_array()) {
       $imgArray[] = $img;
}
```

To view the array elements, try:

```
print_r($imgArray);
```